# java.lang.AbstractMethodError with Spring-data-elasticsearch

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm using:

- Those versions:

  1. Spring core 4.3.7
  2. Spring-data-elasticsearch 3.0.9 RELEASE
  3. ES: "version": "6.3.0"
  4. org.elasticsearch.client:rest:5.5.0 and transport 5.5.0
  5. Spring-data-commons 1.12.8.RELEASE

Created IAuditElasticRepository.java with empty interface:

```
public interface IAuditElasticRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<AuditDocument, String> {
}
```

Created an ch-elastic.xml configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:elasticsearch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch/spring-elasticsearch-1.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    <context:spring-configured />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <elasticsearch:repositories base-package="com.**.ch.db.elasticsearch" />
</beans>
```

Autowired it in my Manager class:

```
@Autowired
private IAuditElasticRepository elasticRepository;
```

And there is a parent xml called ch-db.xml which imports this ch-elastic.xml to it.

I have read latests posts about abstractMethodError, but couldn't find anything helpful. is it related to my Spring Core Version?

Stack trace:

```
2018-07-30 07:02:25,472 INFO [org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate] - Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2018-07-30 07:02:25,633 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:META-INF/ch-db.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [META-INF/ch-ws.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:/META-INF/ch-elasticsearch.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [META-INF/ch-db.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [META-INF/ch-elasticsearch.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.config.ElasticsearchRepositoryConfigExtension.getRepositoryFactoryClassName()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:/META-INF/ch-elasticsearch.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [META-INF/ch-db.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [META-INF/ch-elasticsearch.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.config.ElasticsearchRepositoryConfigExtension.getRepositoryFactoryClassName()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [META-INF/ch-elasticsearch.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.config.ElasticsearchRepositoryConfigExtension.getRepositoryFactoryClassName()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.config.ElasticsearchRepositoryConfigExtension.getRepositoryFactoryClassName()Ljava/lang/String;
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:META-INF/ch-db.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [META-INF/ch-ws.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:/META-INF/ch-elasticsearch.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [META-INF/ch-db.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [META-INF/ch-elasticsearch.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.config.ElasticsearchRepositoryConfigExtension.getRepositoryFactoryClassName()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:/META-INF/ch-elasticsearch.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [META-INF/ch-db.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [META-INF/ch-elasticsearch.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.config.ElasticsearchRepositoryConfigExtension.getRepositoryFactoryClassName()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [META-INF/ch-elasticsearch.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.config.ElasticsearchRepositoryConfigExtension.getRepositoryFactoryClassName()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.config.ElasticsearchRepositoryConfigExtension.getRepositoryFactoryClassName()Ljava/lang/String;
2018-07-30 07:02:25,650 WARN [org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle] - FAILED o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/ws,file:/C:/workspaces/ConnectedHome/Foundation/CH/main/ws/src/main/resources/webapp/}: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:META-INF/ch-db.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [META-INF/ch-ws.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:/META-INF/ch-elasticsearch.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [META-INF/ch-db.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [META-INF/ch-elasticsearch.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.config.ElasticsearchRepositoryConfigExtension.getRepositoryFactoryClassName()Ljava/lang/String;
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:META-INF/ch-db.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [META-INF/ch-ws.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:/META-INF/ch-elasticsearch.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [META-INF/ch-db.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [META-INF/ch-elasticsearch.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.config.ElasticsearchRepositoryConfigExtension.getRepositoryFactoryClassName()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:/META-INF/ch-elasticsearch.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [META-INF/ch-db.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [META-INF/ch-elasticsearch.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.config.ElasticsearchRepositoryConfigExtension.getRepositoryFactoryClassName()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [META-INF/ch-elasticsearch.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.config.ElasticsearchRepositoryConfigExtension.getRepositoryFactoryClassName()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.config.ElasticsearchRepositoryConfigExtension.getRepositoryFactoryClassName()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionBuilder.build(RepositoryBeanDefinitionBuilder.java:87)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Walla I got a Friend !!! I am also badly stuck in this problem

But the weirdest fact is its working with

`spring version ==> 5.1.0.RC1`

`spring data elastic search ==> 3.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT`

using this extra repository

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-libs-snapshot</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

I think the reason its not working is version conflict that spring-data-commons part of spring-data-elastic(it uses above 5) and core spring version (where as we are using below 5)

Also as far as i know Elastic server 6.2 only supported transport client above 5.6.0+
so it should also not support elastic version 5.5.0

Comment: then which versions would you propose for spring core 4?

Comment: that's something I would also like to know 
But if you are using spring boot v2 project it uses spring version 4 and i think there is no abstract method error
and also its all about support you can't use Spring-data-elasticsearch 3 with spring version 4 (this is just my guess)

Comment: Looks like it's really a conflict between spring commons -> then error was related to spring v4 version. so better use spring v5.